# Is there a way I could use javax.smartcard libs in CodeNameOne?

Tags: codenameone

Hello for my project I want to be able to use javax.smartcardio libs, these are Java 8 libraries or lower but I do not believe CodeName One has support for this library.

How could I use this in my project?

Answer (score 0):

We have no plans of doing that. However, you could do that yourself either by creating a library with native integration or by contributing code to the [open source project](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/).